# What should be binding in WCF Client for calling SOAP web service with OAuth Authentication

Tags: web-services, wcf, exchangewebservices

I am having WCF client which consumes SOAP based web service which has OAuth authentication. My WCF service gets consumed by some other service but my issue is about authentication when it consumes web service.

My WCF client, consumes web service using proxy generated classes approach. I am able to get Bearer token for OAuth authentication and pass it to request http header as well however, proxy generated class expects binding configuration as well.

var client = new ExchangeServicePortTypeClient("**EndPointConfigurationName**", "WebServiceURL")

I have tried basicHttpBinding, customBinding (AuthenticationMode="IssuedToken/IssuedTokenForCertificate/IssuedTokenOverTransport"), wsHttpBinding (security mode Message & ClientCredentialType 'IssuedToken" but no luck.
I am assuming due to wrong not supported binding configuration authorization bearer token I am sending is not getting accounted.

I am able to consume this web service from console application successfully where I am not using proxy generated classes approach. So I just required to pass authorization bearer token in header and no binding information.

request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);

Can someone please suggest what binding information I should add in my WCF client which can support OAuth authentication ?

Thanks,

Comment: The binding used by the WCF client must be consistent with the binding used by the server.

Comment: Thanks @DingPeng. here challenge is trying to consume exchange web service using proxy class "ExchangeServicePortTypeClient" so don't have that information.

Comment: Have you tried to use Svcutil to generate proxy classes to call services?